# gulpfile compile only the last file

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-less

I have website that using LESS files. My `gulpfile.js` is looks like this:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var fs = require("fs");
var less = require("gulp-less");
var watchLess = require('gulp-watch-less2');
var embedTemplates = require('gulp-angular-embed-templates');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
var csso = require('gulp-csso');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var terser = require('gulp-terser');
var filesExist = require('files-exist');

function buildLess(arr, outputDir, outputName) {
    return gulp.src(filesExist(arr))
        .pipe(less().on('error', gutil.log))
        .pipe(rename(outputName + '.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(outputDir))
        .on('error', gutil.log);
}

gulp.task('homepage', [], function () {
    return buildLess([
        "./css/homepage/reset.less",
        "./node_modules/components-font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "./css/bootstrap-callouts.less",
        "./css/homepage/global.less",
        "./css/fullpage-footer.less",
        "./node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullpage.min.css",
        "./css/Header.less",
        "./node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.css", // Only this exists on output file.
    ], './wwwroot/css/', 'homepage');
});

gulp.task('default', [
    'homepage'
], function () { });
```

So, all those css\less files should be convert into one big css file on path `wwwroot/css/homepage.css`. **After inspecting this file, I found that only the last file is actuly in the output file.**

Few intersting points:

1. If I change the last file in the list, the output of the file is being changed accordingly.
2. All the files are exists for sure (verified by using `filesExist(lst)`).
3. No errors are being printed to the screen.

My npm versions:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-less": "3.5.0",
    "gulp-watch-less": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-watch-less2": "^2.0.4",
    "gulp-angular-embed-templates": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-concat": "2.6.1",
    "gulp-rename": "1.4.0",
    "gulp-csso": "3.0.1",
    "gulp-terser": "1.1.7",
    "files-exist": "1.1.0"
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh... just found the problem - forgot to Concat the output.

this is the right code:

```
function buildLess(arr, outputDir, outputName) {
    return gulp.src(filesExist(arr))
        .pipe(less().on('error', gutil.log))
        .pipe(concat(outputName + '.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(outputDir))
        .on('error', gutil.log)
        .pipe(config.production ? csso() : gutil.noop())
        .pipe(config.production ? rename(outputName + '.min.css') : gutil.noop())
        .pipe(config.production ? gulp.dest(outputDir) : gutil.noop());
}
```